# Displaying pop-up picture in QGISCloud?

Tags: qgis-cloud

I'm working with 2.14, plugin QGISCloud (free version) and for a shapefile (point) I want to pop-up a picture of my vacation and share it with others. It works offline with the code in the HTML box / expressions:

```
[%CONCAT('<img src="', "Loc", '" width="400"></img')%]
```

"Loc", stands for name and folder direction on my local drive. Backslash like: / (backward-sloping) not `\`(upward-sloping). 
But my question is: How to do it online with QGISCloud? Are there alternatives (with other plugin's).

[image]

Comment: That's not helping for me. I still have problems with displaying pictures, it does not show either in QGIS or QGIS cloud. I am downgrading my QGIS 3 to QGIS 2.18 and it doesn't solve the problem. Here's the warning error: > 2019-02-11T19:08:51 1 Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<string>", line 31, in getFileName AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setText'
> >2019-02-11T19:09:28 1 Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<string>", line 31, in getFileName AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setText'

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you cannot can upload photo's to Qgiscloud.
This link give you a step by step solution for this specific problem.

In sort it will look like this:
1. Make new shapefile (point)
2. Make Qtdesign, dialog menu
3. Make python script to handle the image data
4. Edit the field of the layer
5. Create a maptip with image and content.

Now you can share geotaged photo's with others by a web browser which is desktop and mobile compatible and without installing app's or login on a web page.

[Explanation of FAQ from Qgiscloud website](http://blog.sourcepole.ch/2015/11/18/image-tooltip-with-qgis-cloud/)