# Publish map with qgis2web with pop-up webimage

Tags: javascript, qgis-2.14, qgis2web

I'm want to publish with qgis2web my qgis project. The shapefile, point type needs to be a pop-up image, this image must be from Google Drive.

From Google Drive I made to image public and copy the image link to the atribute field is exactly this: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/NattSenOrovPTKCV3xl7mN4HevVW_BIThT4t5Ew605fZDrT6QeFnftVtS8fJn1Vlg-7Wto-cnxe5WHI=w1920-h858

But result is only a weblink and not a nice pop-up image.

How do I solve it?

I use: Qgis 2.14, Windows, Chrome, Qgis2web 2.33 version (latest version)

[image: Settings]

Existing Q&As about this subject are:

1. [Link QGIS attribute table with Web Image?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220701/link-qgis-attribute-table-with-web-image)
2. [Displaying pop-up picture in QGISCloud?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251892/qgiscloud-html-option-display-a-pop-up-picture/251985#251985)
3. [Adding hyperlinks to pop-up data in qgis2web?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221893/adding-hyperlinks-to-pop-up-data-in-qgis2web)

Comment: You will need to edit the exported code to achieve this. Can you edit your question to say whether you are exporting your webmap in OpenLayers or Leaflet format?

Comment: I want to export it with Leaflet format.

Comment: Github Gist location of index file to comment. https://gist.github.com/Dutchflight/da993b2b0af31aef646b0955bf73e2a5/revisions

Answer (score 1):

In the Gist you linked to in the comment, change line 92 to the following:

```
<td colspan="2"><img src="' + feature.properties['Photo'] + '" /></td>\
```